# TextView on GridView with number of items

Tags: java, android, gridview

Firstly I will show you my `ImageAdapter` code which creates `GridView` with images:

```
package com.example.rafal.gra;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private Context CTX;
    public Integer image_id[] = {R.mipmap.empty,R.mipmap.empty,R.mipmap.empty,
            R.mipmap.empty, R.mipmap.empty, R.mipmap.empty, R.mipmap.empty,
            R.mipmap.empty,R.mipmap.empty,R.mipmap.empty,R.mipmap.empty,
            R.mipmap.empty, R.mipmap.empty, R.mipmap.empty, R.mipmap.empty,
            R.mipmap.empty, R.mipmap.empty, R.mipmap.empty, R.mipmap.empty,
            R.mipmap.empty};


    public ImageAdapter(Context CTX){
        this.CTX = CTX;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return image_id.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView img;


        int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 80,
                CTX.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        if(convertView == null){
            img = new ImageView(CTX);
            img.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(height,height));
            img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            img.setPadding(1,1,1,1);

        }else{
            img = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        img.setImageResource(image_id[position]);

        return img;
    }

    //adding item to bp
    public void changeImage(int position, int image){
        if(position >= 0 && position < image_id.length){
            image_id[position] = image;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

}
```

This `GridView` represents deposit in my game and when I open `DepotActivity` then different items will be displayed on these tiles.

All I want to do is to add `TextView` on every tile (bottom/right corner) which will display number of items (I have a variable "quantity" for every item). Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can set your getView() method to add Dynamically one imageView and one textView, and one more thing is you need to Add one holder class which is help you to better implementation. I hope this will help you.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View itemView = convertView;
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 80, CTX.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        if(convertView == null){

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.layoutSection = new LinearLayout(CTX);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
            params.setMargins(5,5,5,5);

            viewHolder.img = new ImageView(CTX);
            viewHolder.img.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(height,height));
            viewHolder.img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            viewHolder.img.setPadding(1,1,1,1);

            viewHolder.textView = new TextView(CTX);
            viewHolder.textView.setText(("Enter text here");
            viewHolder.layoutSection.addView(viewHolder.textView);
            viewHolder.layoutSection.addView(viewHolder.img);

            itemView = viewHoder;

            itemView.setTag(viewHolder);


        }else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder)itemView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.img.setImageResource(image_id[position]);
        viewHolder.textView.setText("");// you can set your text here

        return itemView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView img;
        TextView textView;
        LinearLayout layoutSection;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have exception on line 'itemView.setTag(viewHolder);'. It says: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setTag(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Comment: please share Error log.

Comment: You mean from Help -> Show log in explorer -> Idea.log or threadDumps?

Comment: Please see my updated answer, just add one line in first if condition nothing more and i think you get solution

Comment: itemView = viewHolder; is not correct because these are different types. itemView required View, not ImageAdapter.ViewHolder.